# Can you get experience for indirect kills?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do I still get experience when a mob is killed indirectly? For example:

- Killed by another mob (a skeleton's arrow for example)
- Killed by an arrow from a dispenser
- Killed by a fall, drowning, fire or lava

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jeb has said that experience orbs are to be dropped only if the mob has been killed by the player, as opposed to a mob grinder.([Source](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/109174421662609408))

Comment: And the game can almost certainly track who fired a shot. Even before 1.8, creepers dropped different items (records) when killed by skeleton arrows.

Comment: Can you define what "Killed by the player" entails? For example, [this mob grinder](https://youtu.be/UpI6yrk2fwk) uses a cactus and fall damage only. The player never makes any contact with the mobs at all?

Answer (score -1):

As long as you personally hit it with a bow or weapon within 5 seconds of their death.